# Having problems encoding a href

Tags: php, laravel

I have a href that I am passing a id in and i need to encode the id. I can not for the life of me get this. Im sure this is super easy just having one of those moments

`<a href="{{ url('/home/facebook',$Ad->ad_id) }}">{{$Ad->CampaignName}} {{$Ad->Ad_name}}</a>`

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: I am using php laravel

Comment: By "encode the ID", what do you mean? The `url` method calls rawurlencode on each parameter passed in (which, by the way, you probably meant to wrap `$Ad->ad_id` in array syntax). What's showing up, and what were you expecting to appear?

Comment: Cant see whats wrong would you mind telling more info about the error

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url) about url, I suspect you want to put the additional parameter in an array;

```
url('/home/facebook',[$Ad->ad_id])
```

Either that, or you meant to concat it;

```
url('/home/facebook?id=' . $Ad->ad_id)
```

Comment: The second option is more likely; the second argument for `url` will get wrapped in an array if it isn't already an array ([ref](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd352a0d2ca93775fce8ef02365b03fc4fb8cbb0/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L365))